# IntelliJ only runs code when every code in folder is compilable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ and run my code, it sometimes finds code, which is not compilable. Consequently, I can't run the code unless I either delete the file or put the code in /* */.

Is it possible to run a class while having other classes which have mistakes/are not compilable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you break up your project into more modules and then compile/run only the current module, while reusing the built version of the other modules (that contain the errors right now).